# oclint-json-compilation-database errors

Tags: ios, shell, oclint

..I am trying to generate the report using oclint-json-compilation

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html -rc=LONG_LINE=120" open compile_commands.json open report.html
```

and I am getting the following error

```
`While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:153:25: note: property declared here
@property CATransform3D transform;
                        ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:166:18: error: property has a previous declaration
@property CGRect frame;
                 ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:166:18: note: property declared here
@property CGRect frame;
                 ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:171:33: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
                                ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:171:33: note: property declared here
@property(getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
                                ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:176:38: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(getter=isDoubleSided) BOOL doubleSided;
                                     ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:176:38: note: property declared here
@property(getter=isDoubleSided) BOOL doubleSided;
                                     ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:184:42: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(getter=isGeometryFlipped) BOOL geometryFlipped;
                                         ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:184:42: note: property declared here
@property(getter=isGeometryFlipped) BOOL geometryFlipped;
                                         ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:201:30: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(readonly) CALayer *superlayer; 
                             ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:201:30: note: property declared here
@property(readonly) CALayer *superlayer; 
                             ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:4:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:214:26: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(copy) NSArray *sublayers;
                         ^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:214:26: note: property declared here
@property(copy) NSArray *sublayers;
                         ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:24:
In file included from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewFlowLayout.h:8:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:9: fatal error: could not build module 'QuartzCore'
#import <QuartzCore/CATransform3D.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
21 errors generated.
In file included from <built-in>:168:
In file included from <command line>:2:
/Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/automation-Prefix.pch:14:13: fatal error: could not build module 'UIKit'
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
```

and so on can any one help me how can I exclude system libraries from oclint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too got the same problem but was able to resolve it updating to OCLint 0.8 from [here](http://oclint.org/downloads.html).